# Activate Windows 8 Mail Notifications

Tags: windows-8, windows-mail

Windows 8 has now the feature of the Notifications, which is also activated in the PC settings. For the calendar I get nice notification while working on the Desktop, but **I don't receive a notification when a new Mail arrives**.

Desktop Notification for Calendar:

[image]

I want to get the same **notification on the Desktop** when a Mail arrives. **How can I activate the Mail notifications on the Desktop?**

My Settings:
[image: Notification Settings in Windows 8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Just found the solution here.](http://www.wingadgetnews.com/turn-email-notifications-windows-8-mail-app-2/)

Open "Mail" and go to Settings - Accounts. Choose the Account you want to get Notifications and activate the "Mail Notifications"

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change the settings in the mail itself.
This is how we have to do.
*On Start, tap or click Mail.

*Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Settings.
  (If you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up,    and then click Settings.)

*Tap or click Accounts.

*Choose the account you want to change notifications for.

*Under Show email notifications, tap or click the option you want.